# List of non duplicated records from column hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I need to find the list of non duplicated records from column in hive.

Support if I have column like

```
A
---
---
1
2
3
2
3
```

I need to return only value 1 which is not duplicated. Is there any function in hive to achieve same without doing a group by value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Group By and Having clause:

```
SELECT A, COUNT(DISTINCT A)
FROM
    testTable
GROUP BY A
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT A) = 1
```

Comment: Is there any other alternate approach available other than group by attribute value

Answer (score 0):

Without using `group by` explicitly you can use `count` as a window function.

```
select a
from (select a,count(*) over(partition by a) as cnt
      from tbl
     ) t
where cnt = 1
```